# React userParams in Const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I successfully got the params from the URL. I want to pass that to const value as below.

```
let { id } = useParams(); //Got the param value
const currentpage = data.page1; //Instead of page1 I want to pass {id} as below

const currentpage = data.{ id }; //This is not working.
```

My actual code:

```
function Child() {
// We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
// the dynamic pieces of the URL.
let { id } = useParams();
const currentpage = data.page1;
return (
<div>
  <h3>ID: {id}</h3>

            <div className="container">
            {                   
                currentpage.map((rows, i) => { 
                    return (
                   //Will return page here
```

Comment: Where is 'data' defined?

Comment: Import data of JSON file

Comment: Please show the import statement and contents of json file above

Comment: not sure if i understand correctly but have you tried data[id]?

Comment: import data from './customData.json';

Comment: {
"pname": "Project Name",
"page1": [{
    "pageName": "Home",
    "content": "xyz"
}],

"page2": [{
    "pageName": "About Us",
    "content": "abc"
}]
}

Comment: Whoa. There's lot's that needs attention here. Why are "page1" and "page2" arrays, when each one only contains a single page object?

Comment: Suggestion:
{ "pname": "Project Name", "pages": [{ "name": "Home", "content": "xyz" }, { "name": "About Us", "content": "abc" }] }

Comment: Then data.pages[0] is first page, data.page[1] is second page etc

Comment: Next question - are you trying to display all pages here, or just a single page? And is "id" the page number?

Comment: If so - rather than currentPage.map you could just get your info to display from data.pages[parseInt(id)]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I changed the json to page1, pag2, etc {
  "pname": "Project Name",
  "page1": [
    { "name": "Home", "content": "xyz" }
  ],  "page2": [
    { "name": "Home", "content": "xyz" }
  ]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205720/discussion-between-brucem-and-new-coder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: change your json data to reflect an array of pages better

customData.json:

```
{
  "pname": "Project Name",
  "pages": [
    { "name": "Home", "content": "xyz" },
    { "name": "About Us", "content": "abc" }
  ]
}
```

Then, if you use id's like /0 /1 /2 etc in your URL for the pages, your code could be:

```
import data from './customData.json';
function Child() {
  // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
  // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
  let { id } = useParams();

  // this is not needed anymore
  //const currentpage = data.page1;

  // the parseInt is because the id will be a string and needs to be converted to an int
  const { name, content } = data.pages[parseInt(id)];

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>

      <div className="container">
        {name}
        {content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```